# Failed to download files using flask | instead it display on the browser

Tags: python, flask

I read through many docs and Stackoverflow questions about how to download files from flask powered website. I tried using `send_from_directory`, `send_file` etc but all the response are same i.e displaying the file content instead of downloading the file.

Example:

```
return send_from_directory(directory="/var/tmp/", filename="app.log")
```

Not really sure if I need to change any apache config or wsgi config.

Comment: I haven't recently dealt with file downloads in Flask, but for other people wanting to help you it would probably be very helpful to see an example of the response headers that are produced by your app, particularly `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, let me see if i can get anything with that.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: HI Rob, I am testing on Chrome and safari.

Answer (score 2):

2020 answer

Pass as_attachment as parameter

```
return send_from_directory(directory="/var/tmp/", filename="app.log", as_attachment = True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how Apache interacts with your wsgi app

You can either force Apache to send the octet-stream headers for particular files using .htaccess or main config or

```
send_file(filename="/var/tmp/app.log",mimetype='application/octet-stream')
send_from_directory(directory="/var/tmp/", filename="app.log",mimetype='application/octet-stream')
```

Please notice that your Flask app MUST have access to the file being sent as well as Apache.

Comment: Ya apache has access to the file, i tried both your options still render the file content on the browser.

Comment: Then apache is probably overrides the flask content headers. Or something in between. Some middleware. Try forcing headers in Apache

Comment: i was trying to figure that out but not sure how to test it.